# SQL "Where" problem

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, query, servidor, where

Estou a fazer uma query em SQL e como restrição eu quero que a query retorne os dados desde o primeiro dia do mês anterior até à data de hoje.

Por exemplo: Se eu executar hoje  (10/04/2019) a query, vai retornar apenas dados inseridos desde 01/03/2019 até agora.

Para fazer isto eu criei a seguinte restrição:

```
SD1010.D1_DTDIGIT>=(YEAR(GETDATE())+ (MONTH(GETDATE())-1) + ('01')) AND
SF1010.F1_DTDIGIT<=GETDATE()
```

Com esta restrição a query não retorna nenhuns dados.

Comment: Bem vindo, este fórum é em português, por favor traduza sua pergunta.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow **em português**. Tal como o nome sugere, o idioma oficial usado aqui é o português. Assim sendo, você poderia por favor traduzir sua pergunta? Caso prefira, você também pode fazer essa mesma pergunta no [site em inglês do StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Você não informou qual o seu `SGBD`. E nem suas estruturas de tabela.

Comment: Creio que o resultado de YEAR(GETDATE())+ (MONTH(GETDATE())-1) é numérico e não uma string de caracteres como parece que você está esperando (em seu exemplo daria 2022 e não "201903").

Answer (score 0):

Tente dessa maneira:

```
DECLARE @DATAINICIO DATETIME;    
SET @DATAINICIO = CONCAT(YEAR(GETDATE()), '-', MONTH(GETDATE()) - 1, '-', '01')
    SELECT * FROM TABELA WHERE DATA >= @DATAINICIO AND DATA <= GETDATE();
```